# Журнал сканирования в DrWeb Enterprise Security Suite 11 версия для Linux

Tags: linux, безопасность, антивирус, сканирование

где я могу найти журнал сканирования быстрой и полной проверки на вирусы.

Смотрел в /var/log/, но там не нашел ничего похожего.

Установлен "DrWeb Enterprise Security Suite 11 версия для Linux"

Answer (score 2):

В Центре управления выберите **Антивирусная сеть** > выберите нужную станцию или группу > **Статистика сканирования** в боковом меню > задайте период (например, дату проведения сканирования) > в колонке **Компонент** нажмите на название антивирусного компонента, отвечающего за сканирование на станциях (например, Dr.Web Agent Сканер для Windows) > откроется подробная статистика.

Comment: стоило добавить [ссылку на документацию](https://download.geo.drweb.com/pub/drweb/esuite/11.0.2/documentation/HTML/ru/admin_manual/index.html?statistic_scan.htm)